# How to upload image using ajax and codeigniter without resetting the form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i just wanted to upload an image using ajax and codeigniter. Getting error which is saying "You did not select a file to upload." even i did select that image.

I recently tried many examples from many sources but did not get my answer. following i show you my code this is giving me the result as "You did not select a file to upload." when i already selected the file.

### This is my view:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="dropify-wrapper mb-4 form-group col-lg-6">
       <div class="dropify-loader"></div>
        <div class="dropify-errors-container">
        <ul></ul>
        </div>
        <input class="dropify" name="userfile" id="input-file-now" type="file">
        <button class="dropify-clear" type="button">Remove</button>
        <div class="dropify-preview">
        <span class="dropify-render"></span>
        <div class="dropify-infos">
        <div class="dropify-infos-inner">
        <p class="dropify-filename"><span class="file-icon"></span>
        <span class="dropify-filename-inner"></span></p>
        <p class="dropify-infos-message">Drag and drop or click to replace</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### This is ajax code:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = $('#formname').serialize();

   $.ajax({
      type: 'ajax',
      method: 'post',
      url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>ControllerName/functionName',
      data: data,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',

      success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
      },

      error: function () {

      }
   });
});
```

### This is controller code:

```
public function functionName()
{
    $config=[
      'upload_path'=>'./Assets/imgs/users/',
      'allowed_types'=>'jpg|png|gif' 
    ];       
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload(')){
        $data=$this->upload->data();
        $image_path= base_url("Assets/imgs/users/".$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext']);
        $result= $image_path;
    }else{
        $result=$this->upload->display_errors('','');
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use dropzone js

Comment: when i submit the form without ajax the file is uploading but when use ajax the file is not uploading

Answer (score 0):

Please add  tag in your html and also use formdata in jquery code like below.

HTML Code:

```
<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
  data:  new FormData(formid),
```

Comment: yeah i have the html code like <?php echo form_open_multipart('', 'class="form" id="formid"'); ?>